# To hide the keyborad on background touch in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

yeah!
i have written the code inside  viewDidLoad method but work properly!!!

my prolblem is that my login button not fire the event and application terminated

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self 
       action:@selector(backgroundTouch)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

this is the my method-------------------

```
-(IBAction)backgroundTouch
{
    [txtUserName resignFirstResponder];

    [txtPass resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you have connected `UItextView`s to their instance in `xib`. and check whether those functions are being called or not by keeping breakpoints in your code.

Comment: yeah i have programmtically created the textfield and button  so no chance to check on nib file......

Comment: Have you set the delegate properties of the textViews? If yes, and your breakpoint all gets called in the function then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you have write in this block

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[txtPass resignFirstResponder];

}
```

second method is write the code like this

```
-(void)viewDidUnload
{
[txtPass resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: did you check whether the touches began method is called or not?

Comment: yes method is call but my login button does nothing ,means when we click on login button doesn't do anything  even doesn't print  on nsslog....pls  give some clue

Comment: did you set the textfield delegate methods?